# I'm lost and confused! regarding functions and scope of returned objects. Why is the object returned from the first function changed?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, scope

I'm new to programming and teaching myself python.

I've created two functions. the first returns an objectA. the second accepts objectA as a parameter.  How do I keep an object "alive" between functions?

```
listA = ""  # a string
print(type(listA))

def one():
    listA = [1,3,2,4]   # within this function, listA is now a list object
    print (type(listA))
    print ("def one:", (listA))
    return listA  # returning a list object called listA

def two(listA):  # def two() recieves object "listA" but its no longer a list object

    print(type(listA))  # why is listA not a list object?
    print("def two:", (listA))


one()
two(listA)
```

Comment: As the other answers have said, you're experiencing scope. As you seem to be learning Python, do have a read of this, it may help you understand the "Pythonic" feeling http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Answer (score 1):

This is like asking "*I have a picture on the wall of my house, and when I visit a friend's house, they have a picture as well, but it's different. Why is it different? if they're both `picture` shouldn't they be the same?*".

And then you go outside and see another picture, and it's different again.

That's what `scope` is - the code in a function is grouped/walled/separated from the other code, the variable names in that code aren't the same as outside that code. The *name* might be the same in different places, but that doesn't make them the exact same thing.

What your code is doing is really:

```
# --- 'outside world' scope at this level

worldListA = ""  # a string
print(type(worldListA))

def one():
    # --- function scope starts
    oneListA = [1,3,2,4]   # within this function, oneListA is now a list object
    print (type(oneListA))
    print ("def one:", (oneListA))
    return oneListA  # returning whatever "oneListA" means in this scope region
    # --- function scope ends


def two(twoListA):  # def two() recieves /anything/ and gives it the name "twoListA" inside this /scope/ region
    # --- function scope starts   
    print(type(twoListA))  # why is twoListA not a list object?
    print("def two:", (twoListA))
    # --- function scope ends


# --- 'outside world' scope again at this level

# this function call one() is going to return /something/
# and we're not catching what comes out of it
# so it's not going to go anywhere and will be thrown away
one()

# call the function two() and pass in the thing called "worldListA" from 
# the world scope
# that content will become named as 'twoListA' inside the two() function
two(worldListA)


# what you expected to happen was this code:

worldListA = one()
two(worldListA)
```

Note I've changed the variable names and the comments.

And then yes, you can change all the variables in all the scopes to have the exact same name -> *but that doesn't make them the same variable*.

NB. if your house has no `picture`, you can see the through the windows and see the picture from the world outside. If your function has no variable of one name, Python will try and get one from the next level of outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of scope. Within the scope of `one()`, you've changed the type of `listA`. But in the global scope (outside of `one()`), `listA` is still a string.

Returning the new `listA` is not enough to change this. You have to assign the value to your variable defined in the global scope, perhaps like so:

```
listA = one()
two(listA)
```

More info: http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Answer (score 0):

You've confused yourself by using the name `listA` for three completely separate variables. The global variable declared at the top of the file, the local variable inside `one`, and the parameter to `two` have *nothing at all* to do with each other.

The way to preserve a variable between functions is to capture the result, and then pass it into the next one. what happens at the moment is that you return data from `one` and then *throw it away*; the global variable is not modified.

You need to do:

```
new_listA = one()
two(new_listA)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `global` keyword to point to the listA in the global scope.

So in function `one` you say `global listA`